# Reflection warning despite type hint to Java constructor in Clojure

Tags: clojure, type-hinting

The following code gives me a reflection warning in spite of the type hint.

```clj
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)

(IllegalArgumentException.
  ^String (with-out-str (print "hi")))
```

The warning:

```
Reflection warning ... 
call to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException ctor 
can't be resolved.
```

The code has been extracted and simplified from a more complex example where pretty printing an arbitrary object is performed within the `with-out-str`. I am using Clojure 1.10.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [CLJ-865](https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/CLJ-865). It's not specific to `with-out-str`: adding a type hint to any form which is a macro invocation will typically discard it. The typical workaround is the one in your answer: define a local saving the value, artificially introducing an non-macro form to annotate.

Comment: I guess this is not going to be fixed anytime soon since you reported it in 2011 and even supplied a patch.

Comment: No doubt they'll get to it one of these days.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the cause, but I'll note it can be fixed with a call to `str`:

```
(IllegalArgumentException. (str (with-out-str (print "hi"))))
```

It seems to be something to do with `try`?:

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)

(IllegalArgumentException. ^String (try "" (finally "")))

Reflection warning, C:\Users\slomi\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init3916067866461493959.clj:3:1 - call to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException ctor can't be resolved.
```

Answer (score 1):

Carcigenicate's insight into the cause inspired me to try the following which also works.

```clj
(let [m (with-out-str (print "hi"))]
  (IllegalArgumentException.
   ^String m ))
```